# Need to change the color of third <h1>

Tags: html, css

```
<div id=owl-slider>
<div class=item>
<div class=slider-text>

</div>
</div>
<div class=item>
<div class=slider-text>

</div>
</div>
<div class=item>
<div class=slider-text>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Each `slider-text` class contain `<div>`, `<h1>` and `<a>` each
How can i change the color of third `<h1>`

Comment: Check http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp. A css selector like `div.slider-text:nth-of-type(2) h1` should work

Answer (score 3):

If you need to change every third h1, you can try this:

```
h1:nth-of-type(3) {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div>
<h1>One</h1>
<h1>Two</h1>
<h1>Three</h1>
<h1>Four</h1>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is definitely a much better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your response but wot about your opinion the class item appears as a loop

Comment: @Vinil it is not a loop. You can check the docs here http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you would like to do it this way, but it definitely works.

Add a class or id to the h1 tag.

**HTML**

```
<span class="red"><h1>Hello</h1></span>
```

**CSS**

```
.red{
color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

**H1** is children of **.slider-text** and **.slider-text** is of **.item**.

**#owl-slider** has many **.items**.

So, we have to go through this and select third item.

```
#owl-slider > .item:nth-child(3) h1{
  color: red;
}
```

Here is codepen demo: [click here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZQwGN)

Answer (score 0):

If you have enable this owl slider then there will by dynamic div added by script with the class "owl-item". So you have to target h1 as below:

```css
#owl-slider .owl-item:nth-child(3) h1{
  color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use nth-child .

```
 .item:nth-child(3n) h1 a 
   {
      color: red;
      font-size: 12px;
   }
```

[DEMO LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/xbp0kryc/1/)